# Multiple cases with automatic braces

Tags: equations, braces, cases

I am writing a relation in which I need to describe the value of `G(i, s, a)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage {amsfonts}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage [margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage {setspace}
\usepackage {subfig}
\usepackage {cleveref}

\begin{document}

\[
G(i, s, a) =
\begin{cases}
G(i+1, s, 0) + p & \text{if } i < n, s=0, a=0, SP[i] = 0 \\
G(i+1, \min
\begin{cases}
s+b \\
A
\end{cases} \Bigg \}, 0) + p & \text{if } i < n, s=0, a=0, SP[i] = 1 \\
G(i+1, s-1, 1) + 2p & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=1, SP[i] = 0 \\
G(i+1, \min\begin{cases}
s+b -1\\
A
\end{cases} \Bigg \}, 0) + 2p & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=1, SP[i]=1 \\
p & \text{if } i=n, s=0, a=0 \\
2p & \text{if } i=n, s>0 \\
\max
\begin{cases}
G(i+1, s, 0) + p\\
G(i+1, s-1, 1) + 2p
\end{cases} & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=0, SP[i] = 0 \\
\max
\begin{cases}
G(i+1, \min
\begin{cases}
A \\
s+b
\end{cases}
, 0) + p \\
G(i+1, \min
\begin{cases}
A \\
s+b-1
\end{cases}, 1) + 2p
\end{cases}
& \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=0, SP[i] = 1
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image: Output]

However, I could not find any information on how to do:

1. Cases for the min/max relations without having to do `begin{cases}` and `end{cases}` (i.e., just to make it clearer).
2. Have the ending big curly brace be automatically placed without having to do it manually.
3. Have the `if ...` condition be automatically placed after each of the outer cases without having to use `&` directly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see, your question is more math issues than LaTeX. Min, Max construction is usuali write in form `\min(a,b)`. Following to this, the answers to your questions are:

-`\min` and `\max` relation should be writen on diferent way, for example as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage {amsfonts}
\usepackage {amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage [margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\[
G(i, s, a) = \begin{cases}
    G(i+1, s, 0) + p            & \text{if } i < n, s=0, a=0, SP[i] = 0 \\
G(i+1, \min(s+b,A), 0) + p      & \text{if } i < n, s=0, a=0, SP[i] = 1 \\
G(i+1, s-1, 1) + 2p             & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=1, SP[i] = 0 \\
G(i+1, \min(s+b -1,A), 0) + 2p  & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=1, SP[i]=1 \\
p                               & \text{if } i=n, s=0, a=0 \\
2p                              & \text{if } i=n, s>0 \\
\max\left{\begin{multlined}
        G(i+1, s, 0) + p,\\[-1em]
    G(i+1, s-1, 1) + 2p
          \end{multlined}\right}
                                & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=0, SP[i] = 0 \\
\max\left(\begin{multlined}
        G\bigl{i+1, \min{A,s+b}, 0\bigr} + p,\\[-1em]
     G\bigl{i+1, \min{A,s+b-1,1},1\bigr} + 2p
          \end{multlined}\right}
                                & \text{if } i < n, s > 0, a=0, SP[i] = 1
\end{cases}
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

-Braces (anyone) cannot be automatically placed.

-For `if` is not necessary to wrote ampersands, but then you lost formatting of math expression, which `cases` provide.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It's a shame there isn't a mechanism for automatic right braces.

Comment: LaTeX is doesn't contain artificial intelligence :-). It just doing what you say ... but if doesn't find the closed braces/brackets ... it will complain.

Comment: If the choice in `\min`/`\max` is from a *set*, the typical notation would be `{..}`, not `(..)`.

Comment: Thank you for information. I will correct the code.  I'm not mathematician ...